# An upper bound of a complex number

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I was wondering if it would be possible to define an upper bound (that is a real number) of the following
\begin{equation}
e^{iat}=\cos(ax)+i\sin(ax)
\end{equation}
where $a$ is some integer. For example what would be
\begin{equation}
\sup_{0\leq t\leq 2\pi}|e^{-iat}|?
\end{equation}

Comment: For real numbers $a$ and $t$, $e^{iat}$ is on the unit circle, hence $|e^{iat}| = 1$?

Answer (score -1):

In $\mathbb C$, $|re^{i\theta}|=|r|$.

Answer (score -1):

Remark
C is not ordered so there cannot be an "upper" bound for a set of complex numbers. However the absolute values may have an upper bound since  these are real numbers.